# CSS text overflows ooh man what a mess

Tags: css, text, overflow, twitter-bootstrap, typography

I compiled this jsFiddle demo so that you can see what i am going throw. Using the Twitter Bootstrap 2 i thought everything was fine and simple things were taken care until i hit with this. I don't understand if the markup is not right or the library doesn't handle this but the text when long just overflows out of screen/container

#### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kSCa3/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `word-wrap: break-word` in your `DIV`. Write this:

```
.span9 {
    width: 700px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: i knew the solution but to ask this is bug / unintended thing with the library is it? then how come when u see the demo page on their servers the documentation with large text are perfectly fine and showing well

Comment: It's not a bug of any library is a normally happening when an text is to long without any space.

Comment: & i presume this is CSS3, clip is css2 counterpart ? or am i wrong

Comment: it's not a part of css3 & it's work till IE6 check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
div {
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}​
```

Comment: @ Ronak - This does indeed work, I updated the OP's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kSCa3/5/

Comment: It should be cautioned that while most are recommending word-wrap and word-break, these are both CSS3 properties and this could become a compatibility nightmare.

Comment: add this `word-wrap: break-word;` also. This might make compatible on every browser

Comment: You can also visit [CanIUse](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap) to resolve browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 5):

I have just spent almost an entire day trying to solve this, and the above didn't work until I discovered this:

Make certain you also have fluid containers INSIDE the floated div:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Otherwise it'll stay the same width and will spill over ..  no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you can try this too :

```
div.span9{
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */

}
```